# A regex for this case

Tags: regex

I can not find a regex for a line like this:

0:1,2,3;
or
23:2,34,0;

Can you help me ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your latest non-working regex.

Comment: You need to be more specific.  What do you want to do? Split into parts (how many? give example results)?  Find lines that match these examples? Something else?

Comment: Sure, we can help - but this question is missing sooo much. Please add a description of the pattern you want to match, what exactly you want to do with regex, why you didn't manage to do this on your own, textcases, edgecases.

Comment: i want to put it in a matrix like in this case 0:1,2,3;1:0;2:0;3:0;
it make that 0 (0   1   1   1)
                    1 (1   0   0   0)
                     2(1   0   0   0)
                     3(1  0   0   0)

Comment: This is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

This should match both strings:

```
^\d+:\d+,\d+,\d;$
```

Comment: thank you! but do you know how to make it if i want that the regex accept this : 0:1,2,3; and this :  1:0; ? Thank you so much

Comment: you can use ()* for section of a string that is not required, like this: `^\d+:(\d+,\d+,)*\d;$`

Comment: Thank you! It helps me a lot